# Set up micropayment via paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am trying to set up micropayments through paypal, but every time I click "get started" on the "selling digital goods" page it sends me to a UK site, and then back to my account over view after clicking the "get started" button on the UK site. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call to get that enabled.  Their [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/digital-goods/IntroducingExpressCheckoutDG/) states that specifically.

> **Enabling your PayPal Account for Digital Goods**
>
> Please contact your sales representative to enable your account for PayPal Digital Goods.
> Additionally, merchants in the US or Canada can contact either
> 1-855-477-5673 or 1-888-818-3922 to activate Digital Goods for their
> accounts.

I just tried something for myself, and seems to be working for me.  Using [this URL](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/digital), if I'm already logged in to my PayPal account when I click Get Started then it just takes me to my overview page like you're explaining.

If I log out of my account, though, and then go back to that page and click Get Started, it asks me to enter my email and a captcha, then it sees that I already have a PayPal account with my email and asks me to login.  When I login there it continues to the DG app.

Comment: ah, that's annoying... why does their website have a process for it then?

Comment: Is [this the page you were trying it from](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/digital)?  It seems to be working for me.

Comment: Yes, it was one of them, when I click "get started" it just takes me to my account overview - doesn't show any forms or additional steps or even a confirmation that I now have micropayments.

Comment: also notice that the phone number is not even a US number, I'm pretty sure this is a UK specific page

Comment: The DG app? When I login after clicking "get started" and entering my email, it still takes me to account overview when I login and continue. Is there no way to do it with an existing account?

Comment: When I put my email in it finds that I have an existing account, has me login through a different login than the usual one, and then it brings me into the start of the DG application.

Comment: Ya know, I just did it again and now it's just going to the overview again.  It's gotta be a session/cache/cookie thing.  Have you tried it in another clean browser?  I switched browsers and then it worked again.

Comment: Hmm, I STILL was not able to get this working after clearing cache and cookies on the new account I set up. I did get the DG app to work with my old email though. But it never confirmed that I was changed to micropayments - which is frustrating. The only way to know is to do a transaction I guess?

Comment: Go into your PayPal profile and look for "My Checkout Settings".  Within that it will list things like DG that you have enabled.